# MySQL delete column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Want to delete column from table

Iam trying delete column from table but get error code 1064 You have error in your SQL syntax : check the manual that corresponds to your

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
DROP COLUMN MyUnknownColumn[0]
```

[column name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lunwD.png)

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message. Also, are you sure you're using a column that contains brackets?

Comment: You say you're using Workbench. Are you using the program's interface to delete the column, or typing the SQL code yourself?

Comment: 14:03:45 ALTER TABLE fx.eurusd30_raw DROP COLUMN MyUnknownColumn_[0] Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[0]' at line 1 0.000 sec . table name contains this brackets

Comment: Sounds like you should properly qoute the column name?

Comment: What quote should I use ?

Comment: Usually, you should use backticks, like `\`MyUnknownColumn[0]\``

Answer (score -2):

The error in your MySql syntax is because you are using square brackets '[ ]' . To drop a column from a table, you should use the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename
DROP COLUMN MyUnknownColumn;
```

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether [0] is part of the column name or not

Comment: It is a part of column name